# Codeigniter tries to load database when loading library

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I use a Laravel API to login user into my Codeigniter system.
Codeigniter tries to load database (thats not configured yet). So I disable autoinit in database.php:

```
$db['conexao_geral']['autoinit']    = FALSE;
```

Even with that, after call ANY library, CI tries to load database connection (that doesn't exist yet).

**So the short idea i**s:
I need to get info from user's database (that's stored in session);
After get this info, then CI can connect to database in all pages (except login);

**Some problems:**
After call SESSION library to get users info, CI tries to load database and fails;

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: @pradeep eu estava dando um hack nos arquivos do codeigniter, quase no final quando li "hooks servem para evitar alteração dos arquivos do framework" kkk. Obrigado, continuarei lendo.